# converting to unix timestamp to timestamp in iso format using d3.js

Tags: javascript, json, date, unix, d3.js

I'm trying to read a json file which contains two columns (date and close) . Dates of the Json file are in unix format . I try to convert them to iso stamp. This is my json file

```
  [{"date":"\/Date(1397602800000+0100)\/","close":17},
  {"date":"\/Date(1398207600000+0100)\/","close":17},
  {"date":"\/Date(1398639600000+0100)\/","close":1},
  {"date":"\/Date(1398726000000+0100)\/","close":1},
  {"date":"\/Date(1398898800000+0100)\/","close":3},
  {"date":"\/Date(1399071600000+0100)\/","close":12}]
```

My conversion code is divided into three steps 
Firstly receiving the date in a var. Then using the "substring" function to cut demanded date part only. Finally , multiply it in 1000 to convert the time from milliseconds to seconds.
After Finishing , I parse the date to d3.time.format.iso.parse format.
This is my code

```
    d3.json("data.json", function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {

 // Convert unix date format to regular format
var dc 
    dc = d.date.substring(6, 24)

    //substring dc Console 
    console.log(dc)

    //convert and multiply it in 1000 to convert the time from milliseconds to seconds
    dc = Date (dc*1000)

    //convert  and seconds dc Console 
    console.log(dc);    

   //parsing the date to iso format  
    dc = parseDate(dc)
    console.log(dc);     
d.close = +d.close;

  });
     // parse format
     ParseDate=d3.time.format.iso.parse
```

The conversion part doesn't work . the substring dc console works correctly.But , the         //convert  and seconds dc Console doesn't convert unix date. It prints the my laptop's date, it prints the current date (date.now)... What's wrong guys , help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you substr a much longer string than you need, unix timestamp has a length of 10, so instead of

```
dc = d.date.substring(6, 24);
```

try

```
dc = d.date.substring(6, 16)
dc = parseInt( dc) ;// to ensure a correct value
```

And javascript date object has a built in toISO function, try:

```
dc = Date (dc*1000)
console.log( dc.toISOString() );
```

UPDATE:

```
var log =  [{"date":"\/Date(1397602800000+0100)\/","close":17},
  {"date":"\/Date(1398207600000+0100)\/","close":17},
  {"date":"\/Date(1398639600000+0100)\/","close":1},
  {"date":"\/Date(1398726000000+0100)\/","close":1},
  {"date":"\/Date(1398898800000+0100)\/","close":3},
  {"date":"\/Date(1399071600000+0100)\/","close":12}] ;


log.forEach(function(d) 
{
    var dc = d.date.substring(6, 16);
    var dc =  parseInt(dc) * 1000;
    var myDate =new Date(dc);
    console.log ( dc );
    console.log( myDate.getTime()); // dc is equal with myDate.getTime() so it's extracted correctly
});
```

Comment: No , it's still the same. What about dc=Date (dc*1000) , the "Date" return the current date !!! Is there another function to b used in this case ?